# How develop mobile responsive mailer

Tags: html, css, email, gmail, responsive

I have created mailer but  when I check mailer in mobile, it's not responsive. whatever changes I make in the tags isn't getting affected in the gmail which has to be responsive. How to achieve this?

[this is the emailer which works fine in desktop version but when in mobile version its not responsive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOXch.png)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Right Horizon Mailer</title>
    <style>
    .main-table{width: auto;margin: auto;}
        /* A simple css reset */
        body,table,thead,tbody,tr,td,img {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            border: none;
            border-spacing: 0px;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            vertical-align: top;
        }
        
        /* Add some padding for small screens */
        .wrapper {
            padding-left: 10px;
            padding-right: 10px;
        }

        p {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            padding-bottom: 20px;
            line-height: 1.6;
            font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .header{
            margin-top: 20px;
        }
        .padding1{
            padding: 12px;
        }
        .heading{
            background-color: orange;
            text-align: center;
        }
        span{
            font-size: 16px;
        }

        h4 {
            text-align: center;
        }

        img {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .img-social:hover {
          opacity: 0.7;
         }
        .banner{
            width: 600px;
        }

        strong{
            padding: 10px;
        }
        .para{
            padding: 20px;
        }
        
        .section{
            width: 600px;
        }
        .marginsocial{
            width: 600px;
        }
        .img1{
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
        }
        .image-text{
            margin-top: 12px;
            font-size: 15px;
        }
        .img-social{
            width: 50px;    
            border-radius: 50%;
            display: inline-block;
            padding: 10px;
        }
        .social{
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        .heading{
            margin-top: 15px;
            padding: 6px 7px;
        }
        @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {

            .wrapper .section {
                width: 100%;
            }

            .wrapper .column {
                width: 100%;
                display: block;
            }
            .socialmedia{
                margin: auto;
            }
            
            .image-text{
                font-size: 22px !important;
            }
            span{
                font-size: 21px !important;
            }
            .img1{
                width: 180px;
                height: 200px;
            }
            .banner{
                width: 100%;
            }
            .image-text{
                padding: 5px;
            }
            .img-social{
                width: 20px;
            }
            .padding1{
                font-size: 22px !important;
            }
            .txt{
                font-size: 22px !important;
            }
            .para{
                font-size: 22px !important;
            }
        }
        

    </style>
</head>

<body align="center" style="background: #e0e0e0; box-sizing: border-box; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; height: 100%; line-height: 1.7; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100% !important">
    <table class="main-table" width="100%">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td class="wrapper" align="center">
                    <!-- Header image -->
                   <table class="section header" style="background-color: white" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td class="column">
                                    <table style="margin: auto">
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="padding: 20px">
                                                 <img src="http://www.righthorizons.com/mailer/september/images/logo1.png" style="width: 140px">   
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <!-- banner image -->
                        <table class="section" style="background-color: white" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td class="column">
                                    <table>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="left">
                                                    <img src="http://www.righthorizons.com/mailer/september/images/banner.jpg" class="banner" />
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                       <!-- content -->
                        <table class="section" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td class="column">
                                    <table>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <div class="content" style="background-color: white">
                                                        <p class="para">The news in the local Tv channel shows "Mariam George who lost her beautiful house worth 75lakh at kumarakam in the recent floods is in the resue-camps. She says how she decorated her house with beautifully carved furniture and how much was spent on decorations, The trail of devastation by Kerala floods left 12 lakh people homeless and property worth Rs 20,000 crore lost. Immediately this gave a thought..How prepared are we in this situation???</p>
                                                    </div>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <!-- three columns withs images -->

                        <table class="section" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="background-color: white">
                            <tr>
                                <td class="column" width="200px" valign="top">
                                    <table>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="center" class="padding1">
                                                    <img src="http://www.righthorizons.com/mailer/september/images/image-1.jpg" class="img1">
                                                     <div class="heading">
                                                    <span>Home Insurance</span>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <p class="http://www.righthorizons.com/mailer/september/image-text">Covers all loss and damage caused to home and its contents due to theft,burglary,natural calamities like flood,earthquake and aircraft crashes.</p>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                                <td class="column" width="200px" valign="top">
                                    <table>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="center" class="padding1">
                                                    <img src="http://www.righthorizons.com/mailer/september/images/image012.jpg" class="img1">
                                                     <div class="heading">
                                                    <span>Purchase</span>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <p class="image-text">Protecting oneself from natural calamities is not possible but being ready for the aftermath is possible<b> @just 10/- per day</b>(at the cost less than a cup of tea).</p>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                                <td class="column" width="200px" valign="top">
                                    <table>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="center" class="padding1">
                                                    <img src="http://www.righthorizons.com/mailer/september/images/image009.jpg" class="img1">
                                                     <div class="heading">
                                                    <span>Buy</span>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <p class="image-text">Home insurace can be bought by both the home owner as well as by the people living in rent.</p>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                              <table class="section" style="background-color: white" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td class="column">
                                    <table>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <p class="padding1">If you have an home insurance already,kindly get it evaluated whether it is opt for the current value of the property.Write to<b> padma.v@righthorizons.com </b> for any queries and risk evaluation of your properties.</p>                                                             
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="center">
                                                  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Righthorizonsinvestments" class="social">
                                                    <img src="http://www.righthorizons.com/mailer/september/images/fb.png" class="img-social">
                                                    </a>
                                                  <a href="https://twitter.com/Right_Horizons" class="social">
                                                      <img src="http://www.righthorizons.com/mailer/september/images/twitter.png" class="img-social">
                                                    </a>
                                                  <a href="https://in.linkedin.com/in/right-horizons-3b8a2240" class="social">
                                                      <img src="http://www.righthorizons.com/mailer/september/images/linkedin.png" class="img-social">
                                                    </a>                                   
                                               </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td align="center">
                                                   <p style="margin-top: 20px" class="txt">V.Padmalochani. AIII CFP<sup>CM</sup><br>
                                                    Risk Analyst and A Certified Financial Planner<br>
                                                    Contact:9980289155</p>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table> 
                               
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean _not responsive_? Looking at the screenshot and the snippet it seems to be responding well to the container width...

Comment: @JustCarty He means when the email is sent to a gmail account and then viewed on a mobile device

Comment: @rahul Here's some tips for styling emails for gmail. https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/12_things_you_must_know_when_developing_for_gmail_and_gmail_mobile_apps-2/ . Can you explain what specific elements of your mailer are not behaving the way you expect in gmail on mobile?

Comment: @jwebb thanks for Ur reply the 3 images next to each other are not getting responsive when we send through Gmail

Comment: Even in the pic which i have uploaded the contents are going beyond the width.It should be aligned in the same way as the images